# How to create abstract class for StatelessWidget and StatefulWidget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, interface, abstract-class, riverpod

I would like to create some kind of abstract class that defines methods that have to be overwritten by widgets that implement this class. These widgets can be a StatelessWidget, StatefulWidget or e.g. ConsumerStatefulWidget (see [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev)).

I then would like to have a function that accepts only widgets that implement these methods.

```
void foo(TheThing thing) {
  // Allow only Widgets that overwrite the method
}
```

Let's say the abstract class would be

```
abstract class TheThing {
  void hasToBeOverwritten();
}
```

For StatelessWidgets I could simply do the following:

```
class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget implements TheThing {

  const Widget1({ super.key });

  @override
  void hasToBeOverwritten() {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

StatefulWidgets on the other hand won't allow me to overwrite the method inside the State class:

```
class Widget2 extends StatefulWidget implements TheThing {

  const Widget2({ super.key });

  @override
  void hasToBeOverwritten() {
    throw UnimplementedError(); // Needs to be overwritten here
  }

  @override
  State<Widget2> createState() => _Widget2State();
}

class _Widget2State extends State<Widget2> {

  @override
  void hasToBeOverwritten() {
    throw UnimplementedError(); // Should be here instead
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need to make use of the ref object from Riverpod which is not available inside the StatefulWidget itself.